# how to render from json file to UI?

Tags: html, css, json

```
The thing i want
```

```
<div className='cards'>
          {
           homes.map((home, index) => (
            <div className='card' key={index} onClick={() => togglePop(home)}>
              <div className='card__image'>
               
                <img src={home.image} alt="Home" />
              </div>
              <div className='card__info'>
                <h4>{home.attributes[0].value} ETH</h4>
                <p>
                  <strong>{home.attributes[2].value}</strong> bds |
                  <strong>{home.attributes[3].value}</strong> ba |
                  <strong>{home.attributes[4].value}</strong> sqft
                </p>
                <p>{home.address}</p>
              </div>
            </div>
           ))
          }
        </div>
  
      </div>


[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpffe.jpg)
```

My website is currently

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXq24.png)
```

This is the source I got from youtube : https://github.com/dappuniversity/millow

I have no experience to do react js :((

Comment: youtube link i found the code : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C4blK6X-D_4&t=7945s

Comment: JSON data can be decoded and turned into JS data structure (If you use a thrid party library, it might just do the conversation for you, for example, Axios). After that, you can map them with React and render your view

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.